# What is the meaning of τ in the output function for recurrent artificial neuron?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, notation

What is τ doing in this function? u(t) is the input at time t, a(t) is the output at time t, a(0) is the output at time 0. I don't understand where the τ came from, so I might be missing something here, but the author makes no other mention of it in the chapter. Thanks!

[image: The output function for a recurrent neuron]

Comment: It just looks like the dummy in the integration, of similar meaning to using $i$ in $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$; the value of $\int_0^t u(\tau)\, d\tau$ doesn't involve $\tau$ at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because t is one of the parameters of integration, it can't be the variable you're integrating over. Therefore tau is being used as a dummy variable stand-in for t within the integral. Because it's being integrated over, it doesn't show up in the final result a(t).